# Improving MVP in Scala

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, scala, mvp

The classical strongly typed MVP pattern looks like this in Scala:

```
trait IView { }

trait Presenter[View <: IView] {  // or have it as an abstract type member
  val view : View
}

case class View1(...) extends IView { ... }

case object Presenter1 extends Presenter[View1] { 
  val view = View1(...)
}
```

Now, I wonder if there is any nice way to improve on it which I am missing...

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to improve on. Maybe it would be clearer with the model included as well...

Comment: While an interesting topic, this is not a good SO question.  It is extremely broad, and very unlikely to have any factual, objective answer.

Comment: @orange80 I added a bounty in case people would find a better solution like how to deal with the View to Presenter cyclic dependency. May have been better to use community wiki instead though.

Comment: @Mark Jayxcela: Unfortunately, I can't make it a community wiki...

Comment: "classical" in what sense? As defined by some papers or by comparison to existing frameworks? For instance, wikipedia points to http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf which shows that there are also ISelection and ICommand interface.

Comment: @Mark Jayxcela, it would have made more sense to ask your own question (so that you can provide details about the *View to Presenter cyclic dependency* and what other issues you think are relevant) and then offer the bounty there.

Comment: @huynhjl Right, I will work on that.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov can you share your full MVP code? I asked question and opened bounty worth, please see it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631080/mvp-in-scala-swing

Answer (score 2):

Nice thing about MVP pattern is that it makes your UI code unit testable.

I'd suggest you to avoid instantiating view in presenter and pass it to constructor.
That will allow you to just mock out the `View` and unit test the `Presenter`.

Replace you code

```
case object Presenter1 extends Presenter[View1] { 
  val view = View1(...)
}
```

with

```
case object Presenter1(val view: View1) extends Presenter[View1] { 
  ...
}
```