# MVP in Scala-Swing

Tags: swing, scala, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvp

Does anybody know some well-written sample projects showing how to achieve MVP architecture in Scala+Swing?

I found only this topics about MVP in Scala + Swing:

- [Improving MVP in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717241/improving-mvp-in-scala)
- [Scala model-view-presenter, traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915041/scala-model-view-presenter-traits)

And second extra question: how you think, it's right to expose GUI widgets from view to presenter not using public getters:

```
def getNextButton(): Reactor // this code in view will be accessed by presenter to setup clickHandler
```

but using abstract fields in traits (as described in second link I provide - [Scala model-view-presenter, traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915041/scala-model-view-presenter-traits)):

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Scala Swing abandons quite a bit of the underlying Java Swing MVC. To give some examples: `ComboBox` has no direct access to the model (unlike `JComboBox`), neither does `ListView`, `Button`, etc. Only `Table` has the model, but not Scala'fied, so untyped.

So if you want to use the existing Java models, you need to go into the `peer` fields of the Scala Swing widgets. If you want MVC with your own models, well, then you'll have to do the wiring by hand.

---

```
import scala.swing._
import Swing._

val m  = new javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel
val cb = new CheckBox    ("Check" ) { peer.setModel(m) }
val tb = new ToggleButton("Toggle") { peer.setModel(m) }
val f  = new Frame {
  contents = new FlowPanel(cb, tb)
  pack().centerOnScreen()
  open()
}

m addChangeListener ChangeListener { _ =>
  println(s"Selected? ${m.isSelected}")
}

m.setSelected(true)
```

---

[This is](https://github.com/Sciss/Model) a tiny library to create models in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small bit of example of controllers in Scala, but might not be exactly what you're looking for:

https://github.com/lrytz/pacman/tree/master/src/main/scala/epfl/pacman